# Can you make Three-Dimensional games in Blender?

Tags: game-engine

I know how to make models and objects within Blender, and I was wondering if it is possible to make games using the models I have made? Is this possible within Blender or do I need to use Third-Party software? Also, If I must use a Third-Party software, which would be the best to use?

Comment: You can create game in Blender using Blender Game Engine (BGE), or you can use some free engines like Unreal Engine 4 or Unity.

Comment: see also: https://www.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

Blender itself has a built-in game engine, meaning yes it is not only possible but rather easy to do.

[Right here is an excellent tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLda3VoSoc_TSS7ht07sCt8zDCyAenOG6i) explaining in detail the process of creating an operating and clean game using Blender Game Engine.

Welcome to Blender SE :)